# Conditional formatting on MAX value row

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a table:

Paration by ID & capture the row of `MAX` value when Role = Red

```
ID    Role      HistID   Date       Style
1     Yellow     101      1/1/17     M
1     Red        101      1/2/17     F
1     Red        (Null)   1/5/17     C
2     Blue       101       5/1/17    a
2     Yellow     201       4/1/17    b
2     Red        301       5/5/17    C
3     Yellow     (Null)
```

Referece the below rows:

```
   ID    Role      HistID     Date     Style
   1     Red       (Null)     1/5/17    c
   2     Red        301       5/5/17    c
```

Now based off those rows apply a condition.

```
WHEN HistID IS NOT NULL and Style = C THEN 'Assigned'
  ELSE'Unassigned'
END Status
```

Output:

```
ID    Role      HistID   Date       Style    Status
1     Yellow     101      1/1/17     M         Unassigned
1     Red        101      1/2/17     F         Unassigned
1     Red        (Null)   1/5/17     C         Unassigned
2     Blue       101       5/1/17    a         Assigned
2     Yellow     201       4/1/17    b         Assigned
2     Red        301       5/5/17    C         Assigned
3     Yellow     (Null)                        Unassigned
```

Not so much the answer here, I would like understand and learn the syntax behind applying `MAX` , `Case Expression` and `Keep` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when matches_flag > 0 then 'Assigned' else 'Unassigned' end) as status
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when role = 'Red' and histid is not null and style = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by id) as matches_flag
      from t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

The subquery is not actually needed.  I just think it makes the logic easier to follow.  You can do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when role = 'Red' and histid is not null and style = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) > 0
             then 'Assigned'
             else 'Unassigned'
        end) as status
from t;
```

Comment: not sure that give the answer I'm asking for. the subquery will find any row that matches that criteria. I'm looking for the MAX line per ID then apply a condition.

Comment: @JoJo . . . This finds the maximum per id.  Do you understand how window functions work?  I should also note that the subquery is not necessary.  I just find that it makes the query more readable.

Comment: but I want to find the maximum row where Role = Red per ID. Then once I have those rows identified apply a conditional statement of. If (that max row we just found) that row = histid is not null and style = c the assigned. else unassigned.